# Emulate a Printer

Tags: printer, emulation

Is it possible to emulate a printer in Windows 7 or Ubuntu Linux? What Im trying to do is test the output of the document to two different printing devices without physically having them.

I work remotely that's why I can't access the dot matrix printer on the other side without having someone over there to print ,scan and send over the results to me. The first test reveal the dot matrix printer is having problems with PDF printing so i have to adjust my settings.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a tall order.  You'd have to have the emulator capture the data and create a bit image of what was printed, in a device-specific fashion (and there are only about 10,000 different types of printers).

Comment: Indeed. I wish I can be there physically to configure the settings but until then I may have to coordinate with my colleague on the other end.

Comment: Or move the printer (or one like it) to where you are.

Comment: But with regard to dot matrix printers, if you can find the basic characteristics of the printer (DPI, etc) and find a different one that comes pretty close, that should suffice for your testing.  (Of course, the problem is that dot-matrix printers of any sort are scarce as hen's teeth.)

Comment: Maybe you can emulate your colleagues?  Then the emulation can change the printer settings and you don't have to bother your real colleagues.

Comment: No emulation is perfect, and it looks like you are dealing with some printer glitches, which are not likely to be captured by emulator. To avoid constantly bothering your colleagues, you can try asking them once to set up webcam at the printer output tray